# Creating automatic page size from polygons

Tags: polygon, print-composer, zoom

I am new to QGIS, so I will try my best to describe what I am trying to do.

I have a line feature, along which I have created an array of the same sized polygons/grey squares. I am trying to create a final document including 1 page for each of the grey squares views. Is it possible to generate a new page with a "zoom to selection" view of 1 polygon per page, and create a total document including a page view for each of the grey square views?

Here is the overall view of the polygon/grey square "views"

[image]

I am looking to make a document like this, but instead of just the 1st 2 views, id like to generate a page for each "view" automatically.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about an atlas. See: [Automating Map Creation with Print Layout Atlas (QGIS3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/automating_map_creation.html) And: [Creating Detailed Maps with the Atlas Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html)

Comment: Yes I have come across these resources but am unsure how to also have the generated maps possibly rotate to match the orientation of the grey square polygon features I have generated. I am wanting the generated maps to rotate to have the associated square polygon be oriented directly horizontal or vertical relative to the map view, and I cant quite figure out how to do this.